# How to get count of a column date wise when using group by on that same column

Tags: sql-server

I got a situation where i have 6 different tables & in each tables there is a column as `CreatedBy`. i have to Count total `CreatedBy` DateWise for each tables & show them in a grid.
For example the situation is like, i want to show how many create operation an employee has done for each tables which will be shown datewise.

Note that `CreatedBy` Columns holds some integer value (id). i have a separate tables for each CreatedBy to fetch his name after joining.

Suppose an employe say on 03/02/2015 Xyz has created 3 rows in table 1, 2 rows in table 2 & asume any value on the rest of the tables.
So resultant table will be like :

```
03/02/XYZ 3 2 anyValue Anyvalue AnyValue anyvalue
04/02/XYZ 6 8 anyValue  Anyvalue AnyValue  anyvalue
```

So i have tried to write a query which is working as of now. but getting wrong values when ever i m trying to get the result datewise. so please help me .

```
    SELECT A.CreatedBy, COUNT1 AS CreatedMasterClass1,COUNT2 AS CreatedMasterClass2,ISNULL(COUNT3,0) AS CreatedPropertyValue ,COUNT4 AS CreatedBasicProperty,COUNT5 AS CreatedVariationClass1,COUNT6 AS CreatedVariationClass2 FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT M1.CreatedBy, COUNT (M1.CreatedBy) AS COUNT1 FROM [dbo].[Master_Class1] M1 GROUP BY M1.CreatedBy)
    A LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT M2.CreatedBy ,COUNT (M2.CreatedBy) AS  COUNT2 FROM [dbo].[Master_Class2] M2  GROUP BY M2.CreatedBy)
    B ON A.CreatedBy=B.CreatedBy
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT M3.CreatedBy, COUNT (M3.CreatedBy) AS COUNT3 FROM [dbo].[PropertyValue] M3 GROUP BY M3.CreatedBy)
    C ON A.CreatedBy=C.CreatedBy
    LEFT JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT M4.CreatedBy ,COUNT (M4.CreatedBy) AS COUNT4 FROM [dbo].[BasicProperty] M4  GROUP BY M4.CreatedBy)
    D ON A.CreatedBy=D.CreatedBy
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT M5.CreatedBy ,COUNT (M5.CreatedBy) AS COUNT5 FROM [dbo].[Variation_Class1] M5  GROUP BY M5.CreatedBy )
    E ON A.CreatedBy=E.CreatedBy LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT M6.CreatedBy , COUNT(M6.CreatedBy) AS COUNT6 FROM [dbo].[Variation_Class2] M6  GROUP BY M6.CreatedBy )
    F ON A.CreatedBy=F.CreatedBy
```

Comment: Do you have a date that tells when the record was created, like `CreatedDate`?

Comment: jpw Yes i have another column CreatedDate as datetime Datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the dates modify your queries to return it too; I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    A.CreatedBy, 
    A.CreatedDate, 
    COUNT1 AS CreatedMasterClass1,
    COUNT2 AS CreatedMasterClass2,
    ISNULL(COUNT3,0) AS CreatedPropertyValue ,
    COUNT4 AS CreatedBasicProperty,
    COUNT5 AS CreatedVariationClass1,
    COUNT6 AS CreatedVariationClass2 
FROM (
    SELECT CreatedBy, CreatedDate, COUNT(CreatedBy) AS COUNT1 
    FROM [dbo].[Master_Class1] GROUP BY CreatedBy, CreatedDate
    ) A 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CreatedBy, CreatedDate, COUNT(CreatedBy) AS COUNT2 
    FROM [dbo].[Master_Class2] GROUP BY CreatedBy, CreatedDate
    ) B ON A.CreatedBy = B.CreatedBy AND A.CreatedDate = B.CreatedDate
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CreatedBy, CreatedDate, COUNT(CreatedBy) AS COUNT3 
    FROM [dbo].[PropertyValue] GROUP BY CreatedBy, CreatedDate
    ) C ON A.CreatedBy = C.CreatedBy AND A.CreatedDate = C.CreatedDate
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CreatedBy, CreatedDate, COUNT(CreatedBy) AS COUNT4 
    FROM [dbo].[BasicProperty] GROUP BY CreatedBy, CreatedDate
    ) D ON A.CreatedBy = D.CreatedBy AND A.CreatedDate = D.CreatedDate
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CreatedBy, CreatedDate, COUNT(CreatedBy) AS COUNT5 
    FROM [dbo].[Variation_Class1] GROUP BY CreatedBy, CreatedDate
    ) E ON A.CreatedBy = E.CreatedBy AND A.CreatedDate = E.CreatedDate
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CreatedBy, CreatedDate, COUNT(CreatedBy) AS COUNT6 
    FROM [dbo].[Variation_Class2] GROUP BY CreatedBy, CreatedDate
    ) F ON A.CreatedBy = F.CreatedBy AND A.CreatedDate = E.CreatedDate
ORDER BY A.CreatedDate
```

Also, the `distinct` keyword is not needed when you do a `group by`

Comment: I had tried to include group by  created date too... ok i'll do it again & check.. may be i had used the joining incorrectly that time.